# How to save the copy of the output of my terminal produced by python?

Tags: terminal, python-3.6, stdout

How to save the copy of the output of my terminal produced by python?

This should redirect the output to the file.

```
file_path = 'terminal_output.txt'
sys.stdout = open(file_path, "w")
```

By the way, how to make it work for coloured output?

[image]

[image]

How to have the output on the terminal and also in the file, please?